# Logitec UNIFYING reciever Says mouse is incompatible

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver

I brought a Logitech M185 mouse today and it bears the unify symbol so i thought do i have a universal receiver.
I was right so i paired my keyboard to it than tried my mouse but it said device is incompatible please use the receiver your device came with.

the problem is it says its universal

I tried googling it and updating the driver (im updating it now)

Answer (score 2):

If your M185 mouse features the orange Unifying logo on the body of M185 mouse, it is compatible with the Logitech Unifying receiver. This logo indicates that the mouse has been designed to work seamlessly with the receiver, allowing for easy pairing and communication between the two devices.

If your M185 mouse does not have the Unifying logo, it will not be compatible with the Logitech Unifying receiver, and you will need to explore alternative connection options for your device.
Please see page 21 of this document

https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1Ps2SnEIVS.pdf

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1184434)

Answer (score 1):

What I figure out from internet searching and personal tries is that the unifying usb receiver does not come with normally purchased products. You purchase it separately and can pair with a total of at most 6 devices. I have a few Logitech mice some of which has no usb receivers and none can use the others' receiver. I will now purchase a unifying usb receiver to be able to use them.

A mouse can be paired with a single receiver at a time. So, to restore the connection to the original receiver (if you have), you need the Logitech Connection Utility Software (*LCUS*).

I have just figured out that LCUS also allows you to pair a Logitech mouse with a usb receiver, e.g., my blue mouse has no left button but has a working usb receiver and I lost the receiver of my fully functioning red mouse, I could match the blue receiver with red mouse with this software.

Links

1. http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/unifying
2. http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/logitech-connection-utility-software

Comment: Will work with any product that display the Unifying Logo only

Comment: i already had a universal receiver from a few years back i just accepted the mouse doesnt support it even though it clearly says it does.

Comment: When you first open Logitech Connection Utility, then select *Unifying Receiver* before clicking to *Next*. When I first received my *UR*, I was just clicing to *Next* and the normal reconnection screen did **not** work.